# pod failing with crash loop while initializing , No logs to debug

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to build and deploy an image in Kubernetes, but when I deploy, it failed with crash loop error, I did add sleep time in that so now it is not failing, but the application is not accessible via the service .

I tried to check pod logs as well but there is no logs at all.
Any Kubernetes expert can help me solve this please
there is a dependency of redis but the basic is not working
Image that I am using is at

The definition file for pod and service file is as below
pod file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: voting-app-pod
  labels:
    name: voting-app-pod
    app: demo-voting-app
spec:
  containers:
  - name: voting-app
    image: 
    command: ["sleep"]
    args: ["3200"]
    ports:
         - containerPort: 5000
```

Service file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: voting-service
  labels:
    name: voting-service
    app: demo-voting-app
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5000
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
     name: voting-app-pod
     app: demo-voting-app
```

Comment: Please add ``` kubernetes describe pod voting-app-pod ``` to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `apiVersion: v1` at the top of the yaml.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: voting-app-pod
  labels:
    name: voting-app-pod
    app: demo-voting-app
spec:
  containers:
  - name: voting-app
    image: mirwasim0/bloomreach
    command: ["sleep"]
    args: ["3200"]
    ports:
         - containerPort: 5000
```

Other than that, I tried your pod yaml in a test cluster and it started up fine with no crashloops

---

**UPDATE**

Removing the sleep command

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: voting-app-pod
  labels:
    name: voting-app-pod
    app: demo-voting-app
spec:
  containers:
  - name: voting-app
    image: mirwasim0/bloomreach
    # command: ["sleep"]
    # args: ["3200"]
    ports:
         - containerPort: 5000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: voting-service
  labels:
    name: voting-service
    app: demo-voting-app
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5000
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
     name: voting-app-pod
     app: demo-voting-app
```

Gives me the following crash out in the logs:

```
$ kubectl logs -f voting-app-pod 
 * Serving Flask app 'app.py' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/flask", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 994, in main
    cli.main(args=sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 600, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 849, in run_command
    app = DispatchingApp(info.load_app, use_eager_loading=eager_loading)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 324, in __init__
    self._load_unlocked()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 350, in _load_unlocked
    self._app = rv = self.loader()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 406, in load_app
    app = locate_app(self, import_name, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 260, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/code/app.py", line 11, in <module>
    cache = redis.Redis(host=os.environ['REDIS_HOST'], port=os.environ['REDIS_PORT'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 681, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'REDIS_HOST'
```

This indicates you've omitted you add the environment variable `REDIS_HOST`. After trying a few more times, I found there's a few other environments variables you're missing such as `REDIS_HOST`, `REDIS_PORT`, `USERNAME`, `PASSWORD`. You just need to add those in like this, (and any other environment variables your script requires)

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: voting-app-pod
  labels:
    name: voting-app-pod
    app: demo-voting-app
spec:
  containers:
  - name: voting-app
    image: mirwasim0/bloomreach
    # command: ["sleep"]
    # args: ["3200"]
    ports:
         - containerPort: 5000
    env:
      - name: REDIS_HOST
        value: "127.0.0.1"
      - name: REDIS_PORT
        value: "1234"
      - name: USERNAME
        value: "my-user-name"
      - name: PASSWORD
        value: "my-password"
      ...
      ...
```

Comment: Sorry I missed that while I copied. it is running because there is a sleep command in that , if we remove that it wont work. and even if it is running also you will not be able to access it using the loadbalancer.

Comment: There is no port in the code, when I tried to build it. in requirement it was mentioned that application listen at port 5000 does it mean while building image need to add the port as well ? or that is not required

Comment: I've updated the answer with some debugging

Comment: Hey @Blender Fox. Great mind with great skill. it worked now.
Btw I have tried this earlier but I have not removed the sleep command and that was leading me no where. But thanks a lot .Much appreciated

Comment: Yeah, if you don't remove the sleep command, then the actual app won't run. The container will just sleep, then end, then get restarted, then end, etc. etc.

Comment: Just one more thing, if you see in the git hub repo that I have mentioned in question, it has 2 paths to access / and /tellmeasecret. for the /tellmeasecret this path requires basic http authentication . Do we have to handle that in definition file ? how will that work as I am not able to switch to that path once the service is up

Comment: No you don't, based on how you've set up your pod and service. All traffic coming in via the service will go to the pod (or pods). If you want to handle the paths differently in the app itself, you can do that via within the code. As far as Kubernetes is concerned, it's passing all traffic for the app, regardless of path, to your app.

Comment: Did you get a chance to have a look at the git repo? because in my case it is failing with an error.
this one is working
```
http://af7ad626a5ea9478b8d5d674c7862da7-725819859.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```
this one is giving me error .
```
http://af7ad626a5ea9478b8d5d674c7862da7-725819859.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/tellmeasecret
```
May be you are able to figure out what is required to achieve that

Comment: Are you referring to "`/tellmeasecret`"? You have not told the app how to handle that endpoint, however, the app does have a "`/supersecret`" endpoint defined, and _that_ does have a basic HTTP auth

Comment: For reference: https://github.com/bloomreach/content-sre-assignment/blob/95c02f6a576608a186015474aec9f1f06c13243a/app/app.py#L35

Comment: That app which I mentioned is available online and I am referring to it in general. may be it a mistake in the readme file saying to  
```
GET /tellmeasecret - this path requires basic http authentication and it will tell you a super secret.
```
rather it is /supersecret. am I right?

Comment: Correct. the readme on that repo says `/tellmeasecret`, but the code in that repo does not define a handler for it. But it _does_ define a handler for `/supersecret` instead. So maybe it's just a typo in the readme

Comment: No problem, please remember to upvote and/or accept the answers :)

Answer (score 0):

I see some environment variables are mandatory to startup the service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: voting-app-pod
  labels:
    name: voting-app-pod
    app: demo-voting-app
spec:
  containers:
  - name: voting-app
    image: mirwasim0/bloomreach
    env:
    - name: REDIS_HOST
      value: my-redis-host
    - name: REDIS_PORT
      value: "6379"
    - name: USERNAME
      value: my-user
    - name: PASSWORD
      value: my-password
    ports:
    - containerPort: 5000
```